# jquery lightbox with django

Tags: jquery, python, django, postgresql

This may be repeated question but I am not able to solve it. I want to use jquery dialog similar to [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) but data is going in database instead of showing on page.

My requirement is that once I click a button from my main page, my form should open. After filling the form if I click on <kbd>submit</kbd>, all form data should go to database and control come back to main page.
Can anyone have any example to show? I am using jquery with Django.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: check out something like http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: @Trufa: This one was useful Trufa. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me.

```
$("#feedback").dialog({model:true,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                autoOpen:false,
                title:"Candidate Feedback",
                Buttons:{
                'Submit': function() {
                 $("#myform").submit();
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 /* submit = true;
                  submitForm();*/
                  return true;
                }
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

Well its kind of hard to tell with the limited detail, but im guessing you have th form popping up with a submit button? are you using jquery-ui? do you have ANY code written?

What you could do is make a standard Django view that accepts post parameters and does all the processing you need then supply an AJAX call with that URL on the button. Maybe something like this (untested)

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
buttons: {
    "Submit": function() {  
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'myapp/django_view_url',
              data: { 
                  field1:'somevalue'
              }
        });                 
    }       
});
```

Comment: :Thank you for your answer. Next time will try to give more descriptions about such questions.